# Call C# event with PHP

Tags: c#, php, dll

I tried connecting DLL with php using **COM**

I am able to call dll functions using php. But i'm not able to receive events.

Tried using com_event_sink($obj,$sink,$interface), not working.

Here is my code

```
class IEEventSinker 
{

    var $terminated = false;

    function C_AllDataAreLoaded(){
        echo "user logged in";
        $terminated=true;
    }
    function ConnectionState($connected)
    {
        $terminated=true;
        if($connected)
        echo "connected";
        else
        echo "not connected";
    }

}

$obj=new COM("VertexFXBOAPI10.CVertexFXBOAPI") or die("Unable to include the dll");
$sink = new IEEventSinker();
com_event_sink($obj, $sink, "VertexFXBOAPI10.__CVertexFXBOAPI_Event");

$obj->SetLoginInfo(UNAME, PASSWORD, IP, PORT);

while(!$sink->terminated) {
    com_message_pump(1000);
}
```

the login function callbacks a C_AllDataAreLoaded function login completed.

Is very helpful if you can solve this issue.

Comment: Where the file C# will be executed? On shell or server?

Comment: it runs in server

Answer (score 0):

Try exec command. It might help to run your file.
Link for the help is follows as:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: no actually, once the login is clicked, the response is done via callback method. so exec wont result a response.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was to

use

**$this->terminated=true;**

instead of

**$terminated=true;**

My mistake. Thanks for your answer.